# Swift date formatter ignoring months

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I wrote a date reformatter but it appears Swift's date formatter itself is ignoring the months. The documentation says this shouldn't be happening. How do I make it not ignore months?

```
let testDate:String = "2020-11-22-11:00"
               
print("start date: ",testDate," reformatted date: ", reformatDate(dateString: testDate))
               

func reformatDate(dateString: String) -> String? {
                   print("dateString: ",dateString)
                   let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-DD-HH:mm"
                   dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
                   return dateFormatter.string(from: dateString)
                                
}
```

this prints:

```
start date: 2020-11-22-11:00 converted date: 22-01-2020 11:00 AM
```

It unreasonably turns all months to 1!

Comment: Why would that affect the month value in the OPs output? When I try it, a dateFormat of `DD-MM-yyyy h:mm a` outputs `Date = 132-05-2021 9:27 AM` for `Date()`

Comment: @DuncanC I felt the need to explain that, so I posted an answer.

Comment: I see now. The OP was using `DD` in both the string-to-Date input formatter and the date-to-String output formatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format string is incorrect. It should be:

```
yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm
```

and

```
dd-MM-yyyy h:mm a
```

`dd` means day-of-month, whereas `DD` means day-of-year.

Note that you should also do:

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

whenever you are using a custom date format.

Parsing `2020-11-22-11:00` with `yyyy-MM-DD-HH:mm` means that you want the twenty second day of the year 2020, in the month November. That makes no sense, and `DateFormatter` ends up ignoring the month because apparently day-of-year is a "stronger" date component. The 22nd day of any year is the 22nd of January.

Then, when you format the parsed date with `DD-MM-yyyy h:mm a`, the month component gets displayed as `01`, and the day-of-year is still displayed as 22.

Here are some useful links to learn about format specifiers, you'll just how much lowercase/uppercase matters.

- [NSDateFormatter.com](https://nsdateformatter.com)
- [TR-35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: I would also add that trying to parse `h:mm a` or `HH:mm` is pointless without setting the locale to `en_US_POSIX`. The 12/24h format will can be replaced automatically from system settings.